# Query for getting Array from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I will to retrieved a data from MongoDb one the file to check is on a array.

I mean I have my collection "colorin" with data as:

```
{
    "_id" : "411",
    "addinon" : [
        {
            "key" : "0001",
            "name" : "ClaroEsta"
        },{
            "key" : "0002",
            "name" : "ClaroNOEsta"
        },
    ]
}
```

so I would like to retrieve a colorin that is equial in KEY = "001"

What would be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.colorin.find({ addinon: { $elemMatch: { key: "001" } } });
```